# Add to List from XElement in foreach loop

Tags: c#, list, foreach, xelement

Program.cs

```
using ConsoleApp2.Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string City_Name = "Gdańsk";
            var doc = XElement.Load($"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/xml?key={key}&query=restaurants+in+{City_Name}&language=pl&fields=place_id");
            List<PlaceIdModel> IdList = doc.Descendants("result").Select(n => new PlaceIdModel
            {
                PlaceId = n.Element("place_id").Value

            }).ToList();
            List<PlaceDetailsModel> placeDetailsModel = new List<PlaceDetailsModel>();
            foreach (var item in IdList)
            {
                var doc2 = XElement.Load($"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/xml?key={key}&place_id={item.PlaceId}&language=pl&fields=name,vicinity,geometry/location,rating,website,opening_hours/weekday_text");
                placeDetailsModel = doc2.Descendants("result").Select(x => new PlaceDetailsModel
                {
                    Name = x.Element("name").Value,
                    Vicinity = x.Element("vicinity").Value,
                    Rating = x.Element("rating").Value,
                    Website = x.Element("website").Value,
                    Lat = x.Element("geometry").Element("location").Element("lat").Value,
                    Lng = x.Element("geometry").Element("location").Element("lng").Value,
                    Opening_hours = x.Descendants("weekday_text").Select(y => y.Value).ToList()
                }).ToList();
            };
        }
    }
}
```

PlaceIdModel.cs

```
namespace ConsoleApp2.Models
{
    public class PlaceIdModel
    {
        public string PlaceId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

PlaceDetailsModel.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp2.Models
{
    public class PlaceDetailsModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Vicinity { get; set; }
        public string Rating { get; set; }
        public string Website { get; set; }
        public string Lat { get; set; }
        public string Lng { get; set; }
        public List<string> Opening_hours { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I'm using goole API places. First I get place_id from city then I want to use loop foreach to save details of every place into list. Everytime everything save on [0] instead populate whole list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `.ToList()` you are creating a new list every time. Instead add the items to the existing list with the [List.AddRange(IEnumerable) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.addrange?view=net-5.0).

```cs
var placeDetailsModel = new List<PlaceDetailsModel>();
foreach (var item in IdList)
{
    var doc2 = XElement.Load($"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/...");
    placeDetailsModel.AddRange(
        doc2.Descendants("result")
            .Select(x => new PlaceDetailsModel
            {
                Name = x.Element("name").Value,
                Vicinity = x.Element("vicinity").Value,
                Rating = x.Element("rating").Value,
                Website = x.Element("website").Value,
                Lat = x.Element("geometry").Element("location").Element("lat").Value,
                Lng = x.Element("geometry").Element("location").Element("lng").Value,
                Opening_hours = x.Descendants("weekday_text").Select(y => y.Value).ToList()
            })
    );
}
```

You do not need the `.ToList()` when reading the `IdList`. The `foreach` works well with an `IEnumerable<T>` and it saves you an unnecessary memory allocation.:

```cs
IEnumerable<PlaceIdModel> IdList = doc
    .Descendants("result")
    .Select(n => new PlaceIdModel
    {
        PlaceId = n.Element("place_id").Value

    });
...
foreach (var item in IdList) ...
```

I also do not see the advantage of having a `PlaceIdModel` class just to store the Id temporarily. Just use the values directly:

```cs
var IdList = doc
    .Descendants("result")
    .Select(n => n.Element("place_id").Value);
...
foreach (var id in IdList) {
    var doc2 = XElement.Load($"https://maps.googleapis.com/...&place_id={id}&language=...");
    ...
}
```